# How to make my animation smooth like a curtain falling down

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation

I have created a flexible pipe and i want it to drop from the top like a curtain falling down smooth way.

[image]

[image]

I want the mesh hit the bottom **( red x axis)** . The animation is getting finish at the middle. The middle part of the pipe wrinkle not seen after it fall down. The bounce of the mesh also to much. I want to make it look realistic as if the pipe falling like a cloth down with a little bounce and going up later. Any way to achieve in a good way other than my method. Thanks

Comment: Don't have the question rely only on users downloading a file. Show the settings you are using for the cloth simulation. Play with the settings for tension and compression for stiffness and damping as well as vertex mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure for the result ... not clear what it should represent in reality - material, dimension, if it use some metal (or other hard) rings etc.)

Example is just

- model scaled in Z axis (to more fit final shape)
- Cloth - Preset Denim with Quality 4, Mass 0,8 kg
- Collision Quality 8 and enabled Self Collision
- first 50 frames used to squeeze cloth up by another Plane collider

[image]

[image]